# If a column doesn't exist in dataframe in spark Java throws AnalysisException

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a `dataframe` which is read from `json` file like this.

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("myfile.json");
df=df.withColumn("newoutputlist",explode(col("OutputList")));
df = df.withColumn("id", col("newoutputlist").getItem("values"));
df = df.select("id");
df = df.withColumn("place", checkHasKey(df,"id","place"))
```

So some of exploded column **id** doesnot have **place** key in it which throw the exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field place in ...
```

My *checkHasKey* function:

```
 public static Column checkHasKey(Dataset df,String key, String value){
        try {
            (df.col(key).getItem(value));
            return df.col(key).getItem(value).;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return lit("");
        }
```

How do you handle such exceptions?
If key is available keep value of the key if not available keep an empty string.

Comment: that depends on your requirements of the error handling

Comment: This is the requirement . If key is available keep value of the key if not available keep an empty string.

Comment: and? does it work? if not, on which line is that exception thrown? have you debugged your code?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to check if a nested element exists in dataframe schema before using it. You can search key in "*df.schema.simpleString()*" instead of try and catch block. Here is a sample code of what I mean. Hope it helps.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType

data = [(("James","Smith"),"M") ]
schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StructType([
         StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
         StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
         ])),
     StructField('gender', StringType(), True)
     ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = schema)
    
if('firstname:' in df.schema.simpleString()):
    df.withColumn("newCol", df["name.firstname"]).show()
else:
    df.withColumn("newCol", F.lit("")).show()
```

Output changes as follows due to existence of keyfield:

```
+--------------+------+------+
|          name|gender|newCol|
+--------------+------+------+
|[James, Smith]|     M| James|
+--------------+------+------+

+--------------+------+------+
|          name|gender|newCol|
+--------------+------+------+
|[James, Smith]|     M|      |
+--------------+------+------+
```